# Newtons Law Of Cooling (And Heating)

Tags: integration, logarithms, exponential-function

Rule is: $D= A.e^{-kt}$, Where: $k,a$ are elements of real numbers, $D$ is the difference between the temperature of the item and the surrounding air, and t is the time in hours since the object started to cool.(All Temps are in Degrees Celsius).

I have a question to do with Newtons Law of Cooling, however, I am having trouble understanding how to find variables such as k, and A in the problem. Without these variables I have no idea how to find the answer to the overall question being asked.

**AGAIN** Rule is: $D= A.e^{-kt}$, Where: $k,a$ are elements of real numbers, $D$ is the difference between the temperature of the item and the surrounding air, and t is the time in hours since the object started to cool.(All Temps are in Degrees Celsius).

John makes a coffee at 65C for his boss, His boss lets it sit for 12 minutes before drinking it. By the time his boss went to drink it, that coffee had dropped to 53C. 30 Minutes later the coffee was now 36C.

Find the Temperature of the surrounding air, assuming it has remained constant during the cooling process.